# Improving a fuzzy matching algorithm in Python

Tags: python, algorithm, string-matching, fuzzy-comparison

**Task**: Take two text files and output 100% matches and 75% matches.

**Solution**:

```
import difflib
import csv

# Imports and parses the files
fileA = open("H:/comm.names.txt", 'r')
try:
        setA = fileA.readlines()
finally:    
        fileA.close()

fileB = open("H:/acad.names.txt", 'r')
try:
        setB = fileB.readlines()
finally:    
        fileB.close()

# 100% Match
setMatch100 = set(setA).intersection(setB)

Match100 = open("H:\Match100.txt", 'w')
try:
    for item in setMatch100:
        Match100.write(item)
finally:
    Match100.close()

# Remove 100% matches from the two lists
setA_LeftOver = set(setA).difference(setMatch100)
setB_LeftOver = set(setB).difference(setMatch100)

#Return the best match for setA_LeftOver[i] in setB_LeftOver that is at least 75% matching.
fMatch75 = open("H:\Match75.csv", 'w')
Match75 = csv.writer(fMatch75)
try:
    Match75.writerow(['File A', 'File B'])
    for item in setA_LeftOver:
                match = difflib.get_close_matches(item, setB_LeftOver, 1, 0.75)
                if len(match) > 0:
                        row = [item.rstrip(), match[0].rstrip()]
                        Match75.writerow(row)


finally:
    fMatch75.close()
```

**Problem**: This works, however the results aren't very good. Here is an example of a match:

```
Fovea Pharmaceuticals SA Kobe Pharmaceutical Univ
```

I can't turn up the minimum percent in Diff by too much because I need to be able to match Univ with University. Also, I can't just make sure that the first words match because some strings start with "The" and need to be matched with strings that exclude "The". Can anyone point me in a direction that would throw out matches that technically are 75% similar, but to a human aren't similar at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up writing a most common word script, and then I removed the most common words. This significantly improved my results as @e-satis suggested in his comment. However, difflib gave me better results than pylevenshtein so I can't mark his answer as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

I would try comparing strings with a tool such as [pylevenshtein](http://code.google.com/p/pylevenshtein/). It allows fuzzy string comparisons.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I don't think this is going to work. It has the same issue that using Diff has in that it treats all words equally. I almost need a way to exclude certain words from being matched so that the rest of the string contains more significant words.

Comment: I'm not sure that would solve the problem (difflib is supposed to be better at "human" matches btw, but both are unaware that "The" is unimportant and that "Univ" is short for "University")

Comment: For that, you can preprocess strings by replacing all strings by a common equivalent and striping unimportant words.